# Echo for status codes?

Tags: shell, echo, exit-code

I'm looking for a tool like `echo`, but for status codes

```
$ sts 120
$ echo $?
120
```

I know you can use a sub-shell in a bash-like environment:

```
$ (exit 120)
$ echo $?
120
```

but is there a way to do such independent of your shell?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question, do you mean you want a variable that would get the return code for a command on *any* shell, like for example Bash, KSH, ...?

Comment: @nKn I'm just curious if there's a utility that will take a value as input and exit with that value. Purely academic.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a very simple script that checks if a parameter is passed and otherwise return `0`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
  # There's no parameter
  exit 0
else
  exit $1
fi
```

Give it execution permissions (`chmod +x returnscript.sh`). Ways of invoking the script within a different script:

**Way 1**:

```
/path/to/returnscript.sh 100
retcode=$?
# retcode = 100
```

**Way 2**:

```
/path/to/returnscript.sh
retcode=$?
# retcode = 0
```

Comment: Thanks. I was really just asking if there exists a utility that I may not know about... there are a lot of weird utilities out there, like `cowsay`. I was simply curious if one exists that exits with a return value passed as a parameter (= I don't understand why people look down on questions if they can't understand why someone might ask them...

Comment: I'm afraid there's not such a tool, it can be easily created though.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand the question. 
You seem to be looking for a command whose exit status you can specify
on the command line, without using functionality that's built in to the shell. 
Why?  Is there some shell where `(exit 120)` doesn't work?

Here are some possibilities:

- `awk 'BEGIN {exit 120}'`
- `echo | sed 'q120'`
- `sh -c "exit 120"`
- Write your own script that does `exit "$1"`.

Comment: I'm just curious.. no practical reason other than wanting to test how the `bash -e` builtin worked.

Comment: You could do that perfectly well with `(exit 120)`.

Comment: Indeed, as I stated in the question. But that's not the point of the question (;

Comment: Well, that's the point of my question — I don't understand the point of your question.  Meanwhile, I have given you four answers — what is your response?